# HTML5 video screenshot

Tags: javascript, html, video, canvas, screenshot

I'm trying to take a screenshot of video with predefined time in the movie. So I tried it with the canvas element. The thing is that the video must be playing when you draw the image of the video, but I need the image to still be paused. So I tried this:

```
video.play();
context.drawImage(video,0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
video.pause();
```

But as you probably can imagine, the video pauses before the canvas is done drawing, resulting in no screenshot. So is there a callback function for drawImage? In my case, the drawing process takes about 50ms, but it doesn't feel safe to do:

```
setTimeout(function() { video.pause(); }, 50);
```

Comment: hehe, seems like these canvas and video questions is hard to find an answer for

Comment: check out this article, should be helpful and has a video screenshot demo with HTML5 canvas: http://techslides.com/create-youtube-screenshots-with-html5-and-canvas/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm...it seems like it actually is possible to draw an image from a paused video. Just keep the interval going from the beginning.

Comment: He could and it was a good answer, but it wasn't what made my issue work. Based on testing I found out that it could be done without slowing down the video.

Comment: Can some one provide full details on how to do it. I am stuck on this

Answer (score 2):

Rather than pausing you could try setting the video's playbackrate to something very low (or zero if that works?):

```
video.playbackRate = 0.0001; // or 0
```

This will effectively pause the video for you.

You could also set the canvas to black, tranparency 0.99 and then scan the resulting image in your timeout for a non-black pixel:

```
setTimeout(function() { 
  pixel = context.getImageData(image.width/2, image.height/2, 1, 1);
  // do something with the pixel, kick off another timeout if it is still has transparency
}, 50);
```

When using the last method the video must be from the same domain as the script, and will not work on local files because of security constraints.

Comment: Sweet, that should actually work. +1 for the answer and I'll get back here when I've tried it out!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is what you're after, but have you tried taking the screenshot manually using [MWSnap](http://www.mirekw.com/winfreeware/mwsnap.html)? It freezes the screen while you are taking the screenshot so I guess it might work for you.